# Help with MS Access queries

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access database with 2 tables and I would like a query which lists items which are in one table but not the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    select a.* 
    from TableA as a
    left join TableB as b
    on a.Col = b.Col
    where isNull(b.Col)
```